# return flat text from .net webservice?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have function called  getdoctor () in asmx file I wannna call this webmethod from javascript  and get the result into flat text i.e  i wanna get the name doctor name not in neither in xml or json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASMX web services doesn't support this. You could write a generic handler `.ashx`:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>
using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler 
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("some plain text");
    }

    public bool IsReusable 
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Now you could call your handler from javascript: `http://yoursite.com/getdoctor.ashx`.

Another option is to use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any wrapping, why expose it as asmx? Just a vanilla handler (ashx) would be fine - just write text to the response and set the content-type to text/plain

With MVC you could just return a string from an action.